# Java: Timezone why different timezone give same value in millisec

Tags: java

I have following code, my target is going to return `GMT+0` time in millisec. But Why I always get my local timezone millisec?

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("Time zone id is:"+cal.getTimeZone().getID()+";time in millisec:"+cal.getTimeInMillis());
System.out.println("Time zone id is:"+cal2.getTimeZone().getID()+";time in millisec:"+cal2.getTimeInMillis());
```

**The output is**
Time zone id is:GMT;time in millisec:`1332740915154`
Time zone id is:Europe/Helsinki;time in millisec:`1332740915154`

Why different Timezone give SAME value in millisec?
I suppose if it is `GMT+0` then it should be different value in millisec against local time zone.

Comment: Whats the time zone in your system?

Comment: What about System.currentTimeMillis();?

Comment: My time zone is GMT+2 with summer time

Comment: Modern comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar` and `TimeZone`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). And `ZoneId` if you need to represent time zones.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Why different Timezone give SAME value in millisec?

Because that's what it's *meant* to do. From the documentation:

> (Returns) the current time as UTC milliseconds from the epoch.

In other words, it's the value which would be in the `Date` returned by `getTime` - it doesn't depend on the time zone. If you want values which depend on the time zone, use `Calendar.Get(Calendar.YEAR)` etc.

Both `Calendar.getTime()` and `Calendar.getTimeInMillis()` return values representing the *instant* in time within the calendar, which is independent of both time zone and calendar system.

Comment: My doubt is timezone gives milliseconds or it gives only the requested timezone?

Comment: @sans481: I don't know what you're asking, I'm afraid - could you rephrase the question?

Comment: I am not getting exactly what returns "the current time as UTC milliseconds from the epoch."

Comment: @sans481: It means the number of milliseconds which have elapsed since the Unix epoch of "Midnight January 1st 1970, UTC".

Comment: What about System.currentTimeMillis()? Does it independent of TimeZone?

Comment: It seems it is independ of timezone also.

Comment: @user84592: That's why I said "both time zone and calendar independent". I'll edit it to clarify slightly...

Comment: "If you want values which depend on the time zone, use Calendar.Get(Calendar.YEAR) etc." -- Just what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The `millisec` of a Date object in **Java** is just the milliseconds since `GMT+0 1970/01/01 00:00:00`. It's independent of the Time Zone. Time Zone is a property to format the Date to a readable string.

Comment: That's not really what time zones are for; that's more like what calendars are for. Time zones are to convert between UTC and local time.

Answer (score 1):

getTimeInMillis() method return the current time as UTC milliseconds from the epoch. So, you are getting same milliseconds even both calendar object has different timezone.