# java - How to get the specific time in TimeZone class

Tags: java, timezone

somebody please tell me how to get the time from the TimeZone class. When I run this code

```
System.out.println("Default Timezone: " + TimeZone.getDefault())
```

I got this

```
Default Timezone: sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Manila",offset=28800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=10,lastRule=null]
```

I can't find any function that will get the time such as `TimeZone.getDefault().getTime()`. Please help.

Comment: Question is not clear. Are you asking for the current time-of-day for a particular time zone? Or are you asking for information about a time zone itself, its offset from UTC?

Answer (score 4):

Try below to get the time for EST TimeZone:

```
TimeZone est = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(est);
System.out.println(calendar.getTime());     //<-prints the date
System.out.println(calendar.getTimeInMillis()); //<-prints the time in milliseconds
```

You can change timezone to other timezones e.g. PST to get the time in other timezones:

```
TimeZone pst = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
calendar.setTimeZone(pst);
System.out.println(calendar.getTime());      //<-prints the date
System.out.println(calendar.getTimeInMillis()); //<-prints the time in milliseconds
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Negative Voter: Please leave a comment to help understand, what's wrong?

Comment: Both Calendar.getTime() and Calendar.getTimeInMillis() return values representing the instant in time within the calendar, which is independent of both time zone and calendar system. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9867266/2112688

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), `TimeZone`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3):

```
Date theCurrentDateAndTime = new GregorianCalendar(timeZone).getTime();
```

Answer (score 2):

[TimeZone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) is a abstract class which represent timezone not time. As you mentioned you are invoking the getDefault(),`TimeZone.getDefault()` by using getDefault() you will get the timezone based on where the program is running.

If you want to just print the date, then you have options like [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) or [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)
or if you wish to move with timezone specific time then set the timezone and get the time of that zone.

**Your program** will print the date in this way(this is not only the way):

```
    TimeZone defaultTimezone = TimeZone.getDefault();
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(defaultTimezone);
    System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

The TimeZone class represents a time zone not the time. You will have to use either the [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) or the [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class instead for the time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use either `Date` (or) `Calendar` API to get today date/time.

These APIs use default time zone configured in your system.

Answer (score 1):

You don't.

[Javadoc for TimeZone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html). You'll note this has nothing to do with the current time.

See [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalTime.now(                    // Capture the current time-of-day for a particular time zone. Result discards the zone, leaving an object unaware of any zone or offset.
    ZoneId.of( "Asia/Manila" )    // Represent the time zone, the history of past, present, and future changes in offset for a specific region.
)
```

> 23:45

## java.time

The modern approach to date-time handling uses the *java.time* classes that supplanted the troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

Your Question is unclear? Are you asking for the current time-of-day for a particular time zone? Or are you asking for information about a time zone itself, its offset from UTC?

### Zones

An [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) is a number of hours, minutes, and seconds displaced from the same moment [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). A time zone is a history of the past, present, and future changes in offset used by the people of a particular region.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Manila" ) ;
```

### Current time-of-day

For only the current time-of-day as seen on the wall-clocks by the people of a particular region, use `LocalTime.now` and pass the desired zone. The resulting object lacks any concept of zone or offset as the passed zone is discarded after determining the current moment.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.now( z ) ;
```

> 23:45

For the date *and* time-of-day in that zone, use `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

To capture the current moment in UTC, use `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now( z ) ;
```

### Time zone info

The `ZoneId` and `ZoneOffset` classes supplant `TimeZone`.

```
ZoneRules rules = z.getRules() ;
```

You can interrogate a `ZoneId` about the rules it uses to define the behavior a particular time zone. You must pass a moment (a [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html)), as the entire point of a time zone is that the offset used by the people of that region has changed over history. For example, countries silly enough to practice [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) change their offset twice a year.

```
ZoneOffset offset = rules.getOffset( zdt.toInstant() ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings nor java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).